# Исчезает input при изменении значения

Tags: html, jquery

Имеется див с `contenteditable="true"`, я его редактирую и с помощью jQuery кладу текст дива в скрытое поле `name="name_edit{{ $class->id }}"` для дальнейшей передачи на сервер. И это работает, но есть некий баг, происхождение которого не могу установить. При добавление (редактировании) текста в див - значение кладется в скрытое поле, но как только я удалю 2 буквы с помощью Backspace то Input поле **исчезает** ( в инструментах разработчика смотрю разметку и  его нет) и соответственно на сервер отправляется пустота.

Если удаляю одну букву (1нажатие Backspace), то все работает как надо - в инпуте значение меняется на одну удаленную букву.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

HTML

```
<div class="td border align-middle p-2 name_edit{{ $class->id }}" contenteditable="true">{{ $class->name}}
<input type="hidden" name="name_edit{{ $class->id }}" id="name_edit{{ $class->id }}"  value="{{ $class->name }}">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
     $('div.name_edit{{ $class->id }}').on('keyup',function(e){
         var name_edit = $('div.name_edit{{ $class->id }}').text();
         $('input#name_edit{{ $class->id }}').val(name_edit);
     });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, вы просто стираете свой input, который зачем-то находится внутри редактируемого блока. Вынесите его за пределы div

Comment: Как глупо) Спасибо помогло!